# index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] Crashing while scrolls down

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I have five sections in my tableview.In my (section==4) I displaying from my array.When I scrolls down it will be crashing

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 if (section == 4) {
     return [mandArray count];
   }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 if (indexPath.section == 4) {
    [self.label setNumberOfLines:10];
    [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i. %@",indexPath.row + 1,[mandArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (indexPath.section==4){
    return [mandArray count] *20;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks OK, so I would suspect you are changing the array where the data is stored without telling the tableview.

Comment: Yes array always return 1 if array value more than 2 getting crash

Answer (score 1):

The code mentioned is correct. I think you are modifying the **mandArray** while table is being loaded.

The procedure which i follow to load a table from array is like this.

First initialise the array and load contents into array.

Then load table. Also I add row count delegate based on array count.

**If I change the contents of array then I call `[tableview reload]`**so changes will be reflected in the table also.

I think you are modifying the table while it is loaded and not calling reload method. because **row count delegate method is called only once per load of tableview**. And it uses same data and tries to access data based on count. So to update this call reload method.

Comment: I think suggesting the use of `reloadData` after the initial load is wrong; instead use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to provide much better visual feedback to the user and to also reduce unnecessary work.